# Plot Compound Annual Growth Rate (3 independent variables) in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the revenues generated in 8 different countries of a specific brand over 10 months. 
The data.frame looks similar to this :

```
Month    Country    Revenue
1         Fr         1100
1         Uk          900
1         It          800
2         Fr         1200
2         Uk         1050
2         It          900
3         Fr         1350
3         Uk         1200
3         It         1000
4         Fr         1300
4         Uk         1250
4         It          950

# Code to replicate the above mentioned data frame   
data.Frame <- data.frame(Month = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),Country = c("Fr","Uk","It"),
                         Revenue = c(1100,900,800,1200,1050,900,1350,1200,1000,1300,1250,950))
```

Now I have a bar plot of the revenue per country per country

```
plot_rev <- ggplot(data.Frame, aes(Month, Revenue, fill = Country, ymax = max(Revenue)+100,
                   title = "Revenue (in 1000€) per Country per Month in 2014"))
plot_rev+geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

I've also calculated the Compound Annual Growth Rate(CAGR) using the function

```
annual.growth.rate <- function(a){

  T1 <- max(a$Month) - min(a$Month)+1
  FV <- a[which(a$Month == max(a$Month)),"Revenue"]
  SV <- a[which(a$Month == min(a$Month)),"Revenue"]
  cagr <- ((FV/SV)^(1/T1)) -1

}

gr <- data.Frame(x = unique(data.Frame$Country),y= 1:length(unique(data.Frame$Country)))

colnames(gr) <- c("country","cagr")

for(i in 1: nrow(gr)){
    gr[i,2] <- round(annual.growth.rate(data.Frame[which(data.Frame$Country == gr[i,1]),]),digits = 2)
}

# Growth Curve Function
FV = PV*(1+cagr)^T
```

My Question is, is it possible to plot the layer of growth curve over the existing bar plot? If yes, then how? If not, then is it possible to do it separately?
I tried to look at `curve3d` in package `emdbook` but it just takes 2 independent variables.

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: You can always pre-compute the (fitted) values and incorporate that using `geom_line`. I'm curious, why are you using `ymax` in `aes`?

Comment: I am kind of new to R, so I don't know how to add multiple layers in a single plot. Can you please help me with this?

If I don't use ymax, I get this warning "ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead"

Comment: What's PV? Also, I don't fully understand why you give a function you don't use (annual.growth.rate)? Could you please give a frame with FV, PV, cagr and T1 in it? I'm new to this myself, so it seems to me (perhaps wrongfully) you're trying to plot completely different x an y values on top of the original plot?

Comment: @Wave PV is the revenue at any given month of a particular country. The function, annual.growth.rate, is used to calculate the "cagr" values in gr data frame and I am trying to plot different y-values for the same x-values. I hope, I've answered your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no sure of my answer, but could it be that you want simply this?

```
#your function
  annual.growth.rate <- function(a){

  T1 <- max(a$Month) - min(a$Month)+1
  FV <- a[which(a$Month == max(a$Month)),"Revenue"]
  SV <- a[which(a$Month == min(a$Month)),"Revenue"]
  cagr <- ((FV/SV)^(1/T1)) -1
}

# recalculate gr, but faster and more efficient (no loop)
library(plyr)
gr=ddply(data.frame,c("Country"),function(x) cagr=round(annual.growth.rate(x),digits = 2))
#get T as well (although it miht even be shorter to put into your funtion return(list(T1=T1,...))
grT=ddply(data.frame,c("Country"),function(x) T1=(max(x$Month) - min(x$Month)+1))

# Growth Curve Function => just get the values and plot these??
data.frame$FV = data.frame$Revenue*(1+gr$V1)^grT$V1

# plot values with line?
ggplot(data.frame, aes(Month, Revenue, fill = Country, ymax = max(Revenue)+100,title = "Revenue (in 1000€) per Country per Month in 2014"))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
  geom_line(aes(Month,FV,col=Country),size=2)
```

Comment: The plot is exactly how I wanted it to be. Thanks for that! However, the calculation part is not correct, but it's not the point of concern in this question :)