# Dynamic CAGR calculation in R using dpylr

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
 Company    Year    Variables    Data
  ABC        2000     Revenue     10
  ABC        2001     Revenue     15
  ABC        2002     Revenue     12
  ABC        2003     Revenue     25
  ABC        2004     Revenue     30
  CDE        2000     Revenue     5
  CDE        2001     Revenue     8
  CDE        2002     Revenue     17
  CDE        2003     Revenue     9
  CDE        2004     Revenue     34

  #etc
```

I want to calculate Compound Annual Growth Rate (CAGR) for past 3 years.

For example, 3 year CAGR results for each company will be:

```
Company    Year    Variables    Data    CAGR
 ABC        2000     Revenue     10      NA
 ABC        2001     Revenue     15      NA
 ABC        2002     Revenue     12      6.27%
 ABC        2003     Revenue     25      18.56%
 ABC        2004     Revenue     30     35.72%
 CDE        2000     Revenue     5       NA
 CDE        2001     Revenue     8       NA
 CDE        2002     Revenue     17      50.37%
 CDE        2003     Revenue     9       4.00%
 CDE        2004     Revenue     34      25.99%
```

I am using following formula across data by year:

```
CAGR for 2004=((LastYear/PreviousYear)^(1/n))-1
For example for n = 2
LastYear =2004
PreviousYear =2004-2 = 2002
```

**Attempted R code for calculating CAGR for 2004 vs 2002:**

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

year<-c(rep(2000:2004,2))
company<-rep(c("ABC","CDE"),5)
variable<-rep("revenue",10)
data<-c(10,15,12,25,30,5,8,17,9,34)

tibdf<-tibble(company,year,variable,data)
View(tibdf)

#revenue2004<-tibdf%>%filter(year==2004)%>%select(company,data)
#revenue2002<-tibdf%>%filter(year==2001)%>%select(company,data)
```

Calculating CAGR (from [Plot Compound Annual Growth Rate (3 independent variables) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058750/plot-compound-annual-growth-rate-3-independent-variables-in-r))

```
annual.growth.rate <- function(a){

 T1 <- max(a$year) - min(a$year)+1
 FV <- a[which(a$year == max(a$year)),"data"]
 SV <- a[which(a$year == min(a$year)),"data"]
 cagr <- ((FV/SV)^(1/T1)) -1

 }
```

Use tibdf for a in function.
Unfortunately, I am not able to apply function to my data.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function calculates the CAGR for different values of of `n`:

```
calc_cagr <- function(df, n) {
  df <- df %>%
    arrange(company, year) %>%
    group_by(company) %>%
    mutate(cagr = ((data / lag(data, n)) ^ (1 / n)) - 1)

  return(df)
}

calc_cagr(tibdf, 2)

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   company [2]
#    company  year variable  data    cagr
#    <chr>   <int> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 ABC      2000 revenue  10.0  NA     
#  2 ABC      2001 revenue  15.0  NA     
#  3 ABC      2002 revenue  12.0   0.0954
#  4 ABC      2003 revenue  25.0   0.291 
#  5 ABC      2004 revenue  30.0   0.581 
#  6 CDE      2000 revenue   5.00 NA     
#  7 CDE      2001 revenue   8.00 NA     
#  8 CDE      2002 revenue  17.0   0.844 
#  9 CDE      2003 revenue   9.00  0.0607
# 10 CDE      2004 revenue  34.0   0.414
```

I do however get different results than you, but your questions is a little ambiguous about whether to divide by `n` or `n+1`.

**Data**

```
tibdf <- tibble(company = rep(c("ABC", "CDE"), each = 5),
                year = rep(2000:2004, 2),
                variable = rep("revenue", 10),
                data = c(10, 15, 12, 25, 30, 5, 8, 17, 9, 34))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  arrange(Company, Year) %>%  #in case the years are not in order (here they are)
  group_by(Company) %>%
  mutate(lagY = lag(Year), #get the lag year
         lagD = lag(Data), #get lad Data
         t = Year - lagY, #calculate time
         CAGR = (Data / lagD)^(1/t) - 1) %>% #calculate CAGR
  select(-lagY, -lagD, -t) #remove unwanted variables


#output:
      Company  Year Variables  Data    CAGR
   <fct>   <int> <fct>     <int>   <dbl>
 1 ABC      2000 Revenue      10  NA    
 2 ABC      2001 Revenue      15   0.500
 3 ABC      2002 Revenue      12 - 0.200
 4 ABC      2003 Revenue      25   1.08 
 5 ABC      2004 Revenue      30   0.200
 6 CDE      2000 Revenue       5  NA    
 7 CDE      2001 Revenue       8   0.600
 8 CDE      2002 Revenue      17   1.12 
 9 CDE      2003 Revenue       9 - 0.471
10 CDE      2004 Revenue      34   2.78
```

Or a bit denser without making the intermediate variables:

```
   df %>%
      arrange(Company, Year) %>%
      group_by(Company) %>%
      mutate(CAGR = (Data/lag(Data))^(1/(Year-lag(Year))) - 1)
```

data:

```
df <- read.table(text ="Company    Year    Variables    Data
ABC        2000     Revenue     10
ABC        2001     Revenue     15
ABC        2002     Revenue     12
ABC        2003     Revenue     25
ABC        2004     Revenue     30
CDE        2000     Revenue     5
CDE        2001     Revenue     8
CDE        2002     Revenue     17
CDE        2003     Revenue     9
CDE        2004     Revenue     34", header = T)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Your code helps somewhat, but it does not calculate CAGR between **2004 and 2002** OR **2003 and 2001** OR etc. For 2004 to 2002, the leadyear will be 2004 and lagyear will be 2002. So we use **lag** instead?

Comment: @you are correct, the CAGR calculated is in fact shifted +1 I will update the answer